# Unable to boot Ubuntu no matter what (post install)

Tags: boot, grub2

So far I have tried to install Ubuntu 18.10 and 18.04. Same problem with both.

I'm installing these on a Laptop with 16gb nvme (intel) storage and a 1tb hdd.

Note: This is for a clean install, no dual boot. Which means my laptop is currently unusable.

---

The initial install process is fine.

I manage to get to GRUB after restarting, where if I try to boot into any Ubuntu version (including recovery modes) I am met with a terminal.

I am only able to get to the message

```
Gave up waiting for root file system device. Common problems:
- Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
 - Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
- Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
ALERT! UUID=f8e63e5a-de78-4159-8a4e-41bdd363ebd6 does not exist. Dropping to a shell!
```

From there I only have access to the terminal (initramfs)

---

Solutions I have tried:

- (obvious) But changing my SATA settings to AHCI mode
- Booting with the gfxmode as nomodeset
- Booting with 'quiet splash' replace with nomodeset
- Doing anything with 'sudo' gives me `sh: sudo: not found`
- Booting into 'Try Linux' and attempting a boot-repair
- Booting into recovery mode gives me the same initial error as above
- Booting into the previous version, or the previous version's recover mode gives me the same initial error as above
- Have Reinstalled about 4 odd times

---

Any help is appreciated.

If you need me to post any information (i.e. file lists, etc), please ask. I have no clue what's needed

Comment: What brand/model system? Have you updated UEFI, and SSD firmware? What video card/chip? Part of report does not show all the details on NVMe drives, but most of data is there: May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please attach link to the summary report, the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: I guess that after  changing your SATA settings to AHCI mode, you did a clean install. Right?

Comment: It's an Asus Vivobook
(https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B07HJHGDP2/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1)

To my knowledge the UEFI is in date. 

The graphics chip is an MX130

Sorry, I'm completely new to Ubuntu/Linux so I have no idea what the second section of your comment means lol

Comment: Yes, It's a completely new install. Wiped windows.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone else was experiencing this issue. I'm here to help you out.

The laptop I have is an ASUS Vivobook, it has 16gb of Intel Optane Memory (effectively an SSD). The issue ended up being a weird non-detection of the primary storage (in my case, a 1tb HDD).

When I initially bought the laptop, it must have come preinstalled with software that connects the Intel Optane memory and the HDD, so, the HDD was not actually formatted and available as a partition.

Ubuntu (at the moment) cannot properly install onto Intel Optane Memory. I feel absolutely blessed that I am the first to make this announcement.

---

The fix (for anyone in the future):

Hopefully you see this before you get to clean installing Ubuntu.

Make sure you format your primary storage HDD/SDD and install Ubuntu (or Linux in general, I assume) on to that, and do not install it onto your Intel Optane Memory. This will fix, literally every single problem.

If you're already at the command line, and have tried to install Ubuntu over Windows 10 already, the way I fixed it was by reinstalling Windows 10, formatting my HDD and then reinstalling linux.

I'm sure there is a way to format your HDD in the Ubuntu terminal or by going through to 'Try Ubuntu' however, as I am new to the software, I decided to go the safe route.

Regards,

Joseph

---

Edit: During the installation process I personally created the partitions to ensure proper installation on the HDD. After that, it was just a matter of hype after rebooting into Linux

Comment: Just wanna confirm, Ubuntu was installing on Optane by default?  One thing to note: you can format the HDD by using GParted or GNOME disks (both are installed IIRC).  And you should mark this as the solution

Answer (score 0):

Try booting from a flash drive and using gparted to make sure your root partition has the boot flag set and the UUID matches that in the error message you're getting